# jQuery issue with HTML indexes

Tags: jquery, html, selector, indexing

In my HTML I have a `textarea` element with the ID of `Employment[Duties]`.

When I try to access this element through jQuery, it completely ignores it.

I think this is because of the whole `input[type='text']` selector that jQuery has where you can select specific items within the `[]` brackets.

Is there any way at all to get around this?

Comment: Use a different id, use name, use class, use `$('textarea')` etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this to escape the square brackets:

```
$('#Employment\\[Duties\\]')
```

EDIT: This problem doesn't normally apply in plain javascript, so that opens other options for you:

- you can use plain javascript: `document.getElementById('Employment[Duties]')`
- or you can define a variable with `var emp = document.getElementById('Employment[Duties]');` and then wrap it with jQuery `$(emp)` and use jQuery selectors on it.

Comment: @adeneo, you normally are the fast one :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked a treat.

Comment: I will tick your comment as the answer soon, it says I can only do it in 7 minutes.

Comment: It should be noted that this normally isn't an issue with plain javascript -> http://jsfiddle.net/twDPn/

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by not using the invalid `[]` in your id's.

Note: This is allowable by HTML5 draft specification, but I would not rely on this working across all browsers (and then only for HTML5).